# C# esc key not being captured when used on a form with a timer

Tags: c#, forms, timer

The application I'm working on keeps track of bowling scores during tournaments. In it, there's a data entry sheet and a scoreboard. The data entry sheet has a button on which to click to launch the scoreboard form in a different thread.

```
    private void pict_projector_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(new
        System.Threading.ThreadStart(this.openScoreboard));
        t.Start();
    }

    private void openScoreboard()
    {
        frm_scoreboard frm = new frm_scoreboard();
        frm.TourID = this.TourID;
        frm.NightID = night_id;
        Application.Run(frm);
    }
```

On the scoreboard form I have a timer (threaded system.Timer) that ticks every second and checks if it's been 15 seconds before switching the scoreboards TableLayoutPanel to reflect the next playing divisions scores.

```
    private void ttmr_switch_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        cnt_ticks++;

        if (cnt_ticks == 15)
        {
            cnt_ticks = 0;
            ttmr_switch.Enabled = false;
            switchBoard();
        }
    }
```

On the same form (scoreboard) there's a "maximize" button which renders the form fullscreen. To exit fullscreen, I want the user to press Esc. Here is where the problem comes in.

```
    private void frm_scoreboard_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
        {
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            pict_fullscreen.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

The KeyDown event never gets triggered... and I lose control of the form.

After banging my head against a wall for a while, I decided to bring this to you all. Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Do you have a "Cancel" button defined?  Escape triggers the cancel button, so this might be part of your problem.

Comment: I have no cancel button defined...no

Comment: You need to stop using threads and System.Timers.Timer, it will get you into horrible trouble that you [cannot debug](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsui_team/archive/2012/10/31/debugging-windows-forms-application-hangs-during-systemevents.userpreferencechanged.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you set the `KeyPreview` option of the form to true?

[more information on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you! After reading the article you posted, I was able to make it work.